# GP Developer Console doesn't want my Screenshots & Icon

Tags: android, google-play

Here are my images.
I don't now, what I'm doing wrong.
I've bought the access to the developer console today - everything is fine, but the images don't work...
The screenshots are at the half size now, but it doesn't help...
I don't now what to do now.
I've tried so many times, but it doesn't work - the upload takes long

[images.zip](http://rapidshare.com/share/A5257310FD2AAD6418A20F9599DBA247)

#### Google Play:

`Errors uploading to the Google Play Developer Console We're currently aware of an issue impacting some developers attempting to upload APKs or Images to the Google Play Developer Console. We're working hard on a fix, and will provide an update once the issue is resolved.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console is working badly today, i tried to upload apk a lot, and after some ours it passed. What we can do? - Wait, wait until google will do everything they want

Answer (score 1):

Same for me...we need to wait.

There's no way to upload an icon or a screenshot